# A problem with the rotation of objects in c#

Tags: c#, rotation, quaternions

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationPlasmaCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    float LockPos = 0;
    public Transform Squid;
    float SquidRot = Squid.z;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(LockPos, LockPos, SquidRot.rotation);
    }
}
```

I used this code to make the rotation of my projectile (PlasmaCast) the same as my player (Squid). Unity tells me:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'RotationPlasmaCast.Squid

Does anyone know why Unity gives me an error?

Comment: You cannot use a declared variable as a value for another variable declaration.  Instead assign `SquidRot` value in `Awake` or `Start`.  The reason is because Transform is not a compile time constant, it is a runtime value, and therefore has no meaning in a declaration (since the value being assigned is not known at compile time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store the Squid's Z rotation for use elsewhere in your code, you would set your initial rotation to 0 and during your FixedUpdate() function you would update that value to match its current rotation and pass that into your transform like so:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationPlasmaCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    float LockPos = 0;
    public Transform Squid;
    float SquidRot = 0;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        SquidRot = Squid.rotation.z;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(LockPos, LockPos, SquidRot);
    }
}
```

Its worth noting that depending on the heirarchy of your GameObjects you may need to use 'localRotation' instead of 'rotation'